# 3 tabs, one controller, different parameters

Tags: angularjs

I have the following need:

a)  I have a template called EventsGraph.html. It has 3 tabs: A/B/C
b) I have a controller called EventsGraphCtrl.js

The job of EventsGraph.js is to populate chart objects (using google charts). The controller basically does an http.get to a specific URL and renders a bar graph.

Back to the html: All 3 tabs generate graphs. The difference is that A, B and C need to call different URLs. All other code elements of the controller is are the same

So back to my needs:
a) I dont want unique controllers per tab - I know how to do that via states  - that would be code duplication

b) I want that one graph generation function to run within each tab with different URLs

I thought of using routeParams but that won't work as my controller will only be called once for the template file - it won't be called as I switch tabs

I tried converting the graph into a subfunction of the controller and calling {{generategraph(url)}} in the template but that runs into digest problems looping over and over again due to scope data changing

What is the best way to acheive my need?

Comment: can you just give us a plunker to review your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the ajax call to the ng-click of each tab.  Pass the tab ID to the function, and parse it with a switch statement:

```
<tab-button ng-click="getGraphData("A")"></tab-button>
<tab-button ng-click="getGraphData("B")"></tab-button>
<tab-button ng-click="getGraphData("C")"></tab-button>
```

In your controller:

```
$scope.data = {};    
$scope.getGraphData = function (tab) {
      var url;      
      switch (tab) {
        case 'A':
          url = 'url for tab A'
          break;
        case 'B':
          url = 'url for tab A'
          break;
        case 'C':
          url = 'url for tab A'
      }
      $http.get(url)
        .success(function(data) {
          $scope.data[tab] = data
        })
    }
```

Comment: thank you this is perfect. I invoked the function on the "on-selected" event of each tab, so that takes care of loading it in the first default tab as well.